# How can i store each iteration of a reduce function in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, iteration, reduce, functools

In the below code, the output is `38`, and i want a separate list with the output `[34,36,38]`.

```
from functools import *
nums = [0, 34, 2, 2]
sum_num = reduce(lambda a, b : a+b, nums)
```

As the reduce function adds `0` and `34`, i need to append this value in a separate list, now in the second iteration i need to get `34 + 2` appended to the list. and at last `38` will be appended to the list.
what piece of code do i need to add to get the desired output?

Comment: Take a look at ìtertools.accumulate` and `operator.add`: `list(accumulate(nums, operator.add))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a different function.  `itertools.accumulate()` generates all the intermediate results `functools.reduce()` produces under the covers:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> nums = [0, 34, 2, 2]
>>> list(accumulate(nums))
[0, 34, 36, 38]
```

It uses addition by default.  Or you can pass whatever other 2-argument function you want instead:

```
>>> list(accumulate(nums, lambda a, b: a + b)) # same as the default
[0, 34, 36, 38]
>>> list(accumulate(nums, lambda a, b: a + 2*b))
[0, 68, 72, 76]
```

If you don't want the 0 at the start, you'll have to get rid of that yourself; e.g.,

```
>>> f = accumulate(nums)
>>> next(f)  # throw out first result
0
>>> list(f)  # and make a list out of what remains
[34, 36, 38]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), the `reduce` function is roughly equivalent to:

```py
def reduce(function, iterable, initializer=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    if initializer is None:
        value = next(it)
    else:
        value = initializer
    for element in it:
        value = function(value, element)
    return value
```

So, to get each sum as we move through the process, we can use the function:

```py
def reduce(function, iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    value = next(it)
    values = []
    for element in it:
        value = function(value, element)
        values.append(value)
    return values
```

(Simplified since the `initializer` parameter is not used)